# How & through which file new product is get saved in Magento Database?

Tags: database, magento, save, categories, product

When new product is created in Magento, then how exactly that get saved in Magento database?

Which file & function it is needed to save product in Database?

How can we get newly created product's **Category Id & Product Id** from that Magento file or from Code of Magento?

plz guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an observer to monitor when a product is saved.

Further reading:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/events
- http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento_events_cheat_sheet/

Comment: HI BOOMER, I am not iterested in Magento's event-observer model. I just want file or function name that saves product & generate product id & also it's category id to which it belongs to...